# Identify invoking peer/organisation inside Hyperledger Fabric V1.0 chaincode

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is there any way to know the invoking peer and organisation inside **golang** **chaincode** for **Hyperledger Fabric V1.0**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently all API's available for chaincode is described in [`interface.go`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L42) file. At the moment there is no API which will allow you to identify invoking peer and organization inside the chaincode. I think the main reason for that is that chaincode has to be agnostic to that type of information, since all ACL's managed by the peer and chaincode should stay agnostic to it, preserve deterministic behavior regardless of whoever invoking it and be stateless.

If need you probably could try to leverage the identity of the client who created transaction proposal request, by using [`GetCreator`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L42) API:

```
    // GetCreator returns `SignatureHeader.Creator` (e.g. an identity)
    // of the `SignedProposal`. This is the identity of the agent (or user)
    // submitting the transaction.
    GetCreator() ([]byte, error)
```

And then to parse client certificate to learn about the client, also you can also consider to use [transient fields](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L42) to make client to put there relevant information which could be read by chaincode later:

```
// GetTransient returns the `ChaincodeProposalPayload.Transient` field.
// It is a map that contains data (e.g. cryptographic material)
// that might be used to implement some form of application-level
// confidentiality. The contents of this field, as prescribed by
// `ChaincodeProposalPayload`, are supposed to always
// be omitted from the transaction and excluded from the ledger.
GetTransient() (map[string][]byte, error)
```

Comment: This information seems helpful since I am not aware about these. But still I couldn't reach to my requirement. To make it clear about the things in my mind, I am just updating the post. Can you just go through it and please suggest to achieve this requirement.

Comment: it looks that after the update you asking same question as the first bullet from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352182/implement-inter-channel-security-among-the-peers-within-the-same-channel-in-hype, am I correct?

Comment: do you mind to extract the updated section into separate question?

Comment: Actually the first question is one of my logic to implement the updated section, like if I know the invoking organisation, then I can protect it accordingly. But as per your answer I understood that it will not provide such API since the chaincode has to be agnostic to that type of data. That's why I have given the details of the actual problem in the updated section.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I think it will be more clear if I can provide you an answer to updated question in separate thread, where it will make it will be more easy to concentrate on your specific use case.

Comment: Ok. I have added it in a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352182/implement-inter-channel-security-among-the-peers-within-the-same-channel-in-hype. Please go through it and give one suggestion.

Comment: As an alternative approach you consider to read the answer of @yacom here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339422/user-level-restriction-in-hyperledger-fabric-1-0

Answer (score 2):

In fabric 1.1, there seems a new lib **cid** can reach to your requirements.

#### Getting the client's ID

```
// GetID returns the ID associated with the invoking identity.  This ID
// is guaranteed to be unique within the MSP.
func GetID(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) (string, error)
```

#### Getting the MSP ID

```
// GetMSPID returns the ID of the MSP associated with the identity that
// submitted the transaction
func GetMSPID(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) (string, error)
```

For full information your can refer [Client Identity Chaincode Library](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.1/core/chaincode/lib/cid)

Answer (score 0):

The [client identity](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.4/core/chaincode/lib/cid) chaincode library enables developers to write chaincode which makes access control decisions based on the identity of the client (i.e. the invoker of the chaincode).

You can get the id of the calling client by using `GetID` function available in the [cid](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.4/core/chaincode/lib/cid) package.

Few other functions available that you may find useful in the above-mentioned package are:

- `GetX509Certificate` It can be used to get the `X509` certificate of the client.
- `GetAttributeValue` to get the attributes that were associated with the client during the time of his registration.

Other than the functions available in `cid` package, you may find these functions helpful too.

- [GetSignedProposal](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#MockStub.GetSignedProposal) It returns the signed proposal object, which contains all data elements part of a transaction proposal.
- [GetCreator](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetCreator) It returns `SignatureHeader.Creator` (e.g. an identity) of the `SignedProposal`. This is the identity of the agent (or user) submitting the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up on this question by looking for a way to restrict non-members of private data collections to query private data from a peer. I was considering adding a verifier in the chaincode to see if the client belonged to the same organization as the peer.

If you are looking to do the same, use the `memberOnlyRead` attribute when creating the private data collection. You might be able to build more advanced restrictions using this technique.